# I need the sum of numbers from a for-loop that is NOT in a list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, intersection

I'm having a problem returning the sum. I keep getting zero.

I commented the print results for better understanding. Again, my code is returning 0, and not 11.

```
A = [1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0]

def solution(A):

    start = [i - j for i, j in enumerate(A)]

    start.sort()     #[-4, -1, 0, 0, 2, 5]

    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        pair = 0

        end = i + A[i]   #1, 6, 4, 4, 8, 5 

        count = bisect_right(start, end)     #4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6

        count_1 = count-1        #3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5
        count_2 = count_1 - i    #3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0
        pair += count_2          #???????  I need the above added together like this 3+4+2+1+1+0 since 
                                           that's the answer.

    return pair

print(solution(A))
```

Comment: what is "bisect_right" ?

Comment: Why are you resetting pair to 0 each loop?

Comment: @Joy C. Brock put `pair` on top of the loop

Comment: bisect_right takes the end and creates a count of how many numbers are less than the start and returns a count. so for the first number in end (1), there are 4 numbers in start that are less than one (-4, -1, 0, 0). Move to the 6, all the numbers in start are less than 6, so it return 6. Move to the 5, only 5 numbers in start are less than 5, and son and so forth. Hope that makes sense! It's a little hard to explain...

Comment: Have you learned how to write unit tests? Does this code work for other input lists?

Comment: That was my problem! Pair was in my for loop!!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!! It works!!! Yayyyyy!!!!! I knew I had to be doing something dumb! LOL!

Comment: @cricket_007 what are unit tests? Also, I'm not sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've written in the comments, the last count2 is zero.

You're adding zero to zero, the loop ends, and you return zero.

You need to start the counter outside the loop, or you can sum outside too, like so

```
counts = []
for i, x in enumerate(A):
   counts.append(bisect_right(start, i + x) - 1 - i) 
return sum(counts)
```

Which could be rewritten

```
return sum(bisect_right(start, i + x) - 1 - i for for i, x in enumerate(A))
```

Comment: That looks pretty awesome!!! Thank you!!! I've been working on this for DAYS.... so I think I need to rest my brain a bit and give your suggestion a go tomorrow. I've been up since 5AM working on this all over an improperly placed variable. Dang. But it's all good! Thank you again!!

Comment: Welcome. I would also suggest learning about using breakpoints and a debugger rather than relying on print statements